# Batch file to rename folders while retaining numbering system

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to write a windows .bat file code that renames all folders in a directory to something else while keeping the number at the end.  For example "DVD#4" to "Test Folder 4".  I've been trying to alter the various file renaming codes here, but it hasn't worked.  How should I write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all folders have a # character followed by a number, try this (untested) code. Save it inside a batch file and then invoke via a cmd instance.

This test assumes some folder paths. Modify to suit your needs.

```
pushd C:\ParentOfDVDFolders
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('dir /b /ad DVD*') do ren "%%~fa#%%b" "Test Folder %%b"
popd
```

Comment: Yes, that did exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: This assumes `#` only appears once in the name.

Comment: In this case it does.  I may revise this in the future to be more general purpose when I've got a bit more coding experience under my belt, but for now it does exactly what I need it to do.